# How do you submit a bug report for .NET now that connect.microsoft.com requires Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, bug-reporting

Microsoft appears to have removed the ability to submit bug reports for Visual Studio and .Net. If you click "Report a Bug" it takes you to [this page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

If you click "Submit Bug" it takes you [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=27774) where it either tells you

> If you are submitting feedback on Visual Studio 2010 and .NET
>   Framework, please use the MS forums or contact MS support directly at
>   http://support.microsoft.com or call 1-800-MICROSOFT.

If I go to the link they provide for the MS Forms I can not find any place to submit a bug.

Where do I go now that they changed "Microsoft Connect" to submit a bug for .NET?

---

**Update:** Thank you for your help, [here is the bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/754705/setting-null-to-a-directoryentry-properties-value-during-user-creation-thowes-execption) for those interested. Expand out "details" for example code to re-produce the problem.

Comment: I guess bugs for previous versions won't be fixed because you can upgrade to the newest one.

Comment: Use the Visual Studio 2012 Feedback tool.  VS2012 RC required, they will not accept bugs anymore for earlier versions.

Comment: But I need to submit a bug for .net, not visual studio, updated my question to clarify.

Comment: What would someone do if they needed to submit a bug for .net and all they used was Powershell?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical comment or did you actually completely forget to mention powershell in your question?  That would be the kind of reason they are raising obstacles.

Comment: @HansPassant It was retorical, to point out some people may not have visuial studio, the issue is a bug in the behavior in `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Proporties[string].Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*10 years & 4 days later*

For .NET it's https://github.com/dotnet, for exmaple, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues or https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues.

For Visual Studio, Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem, as shown at
[Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 3):

Look to the bottom of the page containing the verbiage you quote.

> [image]

I followed the link, logged in, and got as far as a Connect bug submission form for the .NET Framework:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I missed that link.